# How to access the API using the Azure access token retrieved while signing in?

Tags: azure, rest, api, oauth-2.0

My front-end is using OAuth2 Azure AD. When signing in, this resolves and getting an access token and id_token, which I am sending to the server with each request that then I can validate(in server).

The issue is that, Now I have an API Rest server by Azure. This API is consumed by my server.

How should I consume this API? I've been reading about On-behalf-of flow or generating a certificate for the server. Or should I use the same access token given to my front-end in my server?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the different choices:

1. On-behalf-of flow
2. Client credentials flow
3. Use same token

The main reason to use On-behalf-of is to keep user context in the token.
It'll allow the other API to apply authorization based on the user identity.
If that is something that you need and is useful for you, definitely go with On-behalf-of.
It does have the downside of needing to handle token caching per user on your back-end.
You'd also need to make sure the user/admin consent is done for that API before the call, since otherwise you'll get an error.

Client credentials flow can be used with a client secret or a certificate.
It's way simpler to use than on-behalf-of, but it loses the user context.
The token will only contain your app's info.
If the API you are calling is one you've made,
be sure to define at least one *application permission*.
Currently this must be made through the app manifest (appRoles) in the portal or through PowerShell.
Then you can assign these app permissions to your back-end app in AAD,
and get a token whenever you need it.
There is no individual user consent needed and an in-memory token cache will probably work pretty well.
The advantage here is simplicity.

Using the same token your API receives is usually not a good idea.
You might for example want to define delegated/application permissions/user roles for your API.
Those are more than likely not ones the other API would use.
It's definitely the *easiest* option, but not one I'd recommend in most cases.